# WPF WebBrowser control seems to use proxy (fiddler) but no one is configured

Tags: .net, wpf, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control, fiddler

Yesterday I just added a WPF WebBrowser control to a newly from scratch created WPF application. But invoking the Navigate method with "http://www.google.de" for example leads to a "Navigation Canceled" error message in the control. First I completely disabled my firewall but nothing changed. I checked the IE internet options for an orphaned proxy configuration but there was not proxy configured. After an hour or so I started the HTTP proxy tool fiddler to check if the HTTP request reaches fiddler or if the request fails before reaching it. And surprise: the request reaches fiddler and the web site gets opened. I double and quadruple checked all proxy settings I am aware of:

- IE internet options again (no proxy settings found!)
- machine.config for all installed .NET framework versions in 32 and 64 bit (no proxy settings found!)
- disabling the proxy in the app.config I especially added right now to my WPF application (nothing happened)

A newly created console application using WebClient.DownloadString works! So I think it is not a problem of a globally misconfigured .NET Framework. All other installed browsers like IE, Firefox, Chrome and so on does work WITHOUT fiddler started!

To be completely sure that no proxy is enabled for my process I have read the Internet Options from registry from my WPF application process but ProxyServer/ProxyEnabled are not set:

- [CU]\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
- [CU]\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
- [LM]\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
- [LM]\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings

Please help me! I am completely stumped!

Greetings from Germany,

Tobias

Answer (score 2):

The "WPF Web Browser" is really just a hosted instance of the Internet Explorer Web Browser object, and as such, by default, it adopts the system's proxy settings. Notably, it does NOT adopt the .NET proxy configuration settings, so none of the `*.config` files should be a relevant factor here.

Stepping back a bit:

1. Do you have this problem for *all* hostnames, or just for that specific URL?
2. Do you have this problem when you use `HTTPS` or only for `HTTP`?
3. If you start Fiddler, disable capturing (untick File > Capture) and visit `http://127.0.0.1:8888/` in your control, what happens?
4. Have you tried running your application on a different machine? Does it behave differently?
5. Do you have 3rd party antivirus/firewall software installed?
6. If you run `http://www.bayden.com/dl/dotnetbrowser.exe` does it exhibit the same behavior?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! I am so sorry! It's my fault.....somewhere. I have just disabled my Windows Firewall completely and it works. Argh! Yesterday I only enabled "all outbound connections". That was not enough.. There must be a "bad firewall rule" which does prohibit the connection explicitly. thank you very much for your helpfulness!

Answer (score 0):

I was absolutely convinced that my firewall is not the problem. It's really embarrassing. I had only set my firewall to "Outbound connections that do not match a rule are allowed". Actually there was an old orphaned rule which blocked my application. Fiddler only came to the rescue as itself registers it as the system proxy and was not blocked. As I sad: really embarrassing :-(

Answer (score -1):

Use Uri paramater to Navigate. Example:
Navigate(new Uri("http://www.google.de"));

Comment: And if you really want to use string, use https://www.google.de. See that its HTTPS not HTTP

Comment: You're not serious, are you? Do you really think that your answer is the solution for my problem? I'm running out of words...